# hypcap is not fixing hyperref links

Tags: hyperref

`Hyperref` is not linking to the correct location of the `figure`. Using the `hypcap` package didn't help. I keep getting the error :" you have forgotten to use `\caption`" ..

The document class is available at this [link](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~gpalmer/GT-ECEProposal-ThesisTemplate.txt):

Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,doublespaced,ETD,proposal]{thesis}
\bibfiles{refs,strings}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%Needed to Generate the figures page
\figurespagetrue


\begin{document}
\contents %Generates the figures list.

\begin{figure}[htb]

  \centering
  \centerline{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{graphics.png}}

\caption{fig1}
 \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try to make the example without non-standard classes (`[thesis][1].cls`) and packages (`insfig.sty`). Otherwise the non-standard files are needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hope it looks better now. I don't have the dtx file generating the class.

Comment: @hasan: heiko asked for a version of your source without the non-standard `thesis.cls` -- how do we debug your code without access to all of the files you use?

Comment: I get no error and a correct link (albeit at the foot of the caption), without `hypcap`.

Comment: @egreg I'm seeing the link going to one line below the caption. You need to scroll upward to see the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you're using already tries being `hyperref` savvy: here's some code from it

```
312    \if@hyperrefused%
313       \typeout{This should not be output.}
314       \hypersetup{%
315          plainpages=true,
316          breaklinks=true,% not default in dvips mode, so we must specify
317          hypertexnames=false,%not ideal, but needed when pagenums duplicate (`i' vs. `1')
318          pageanchor=true,
319          colorlinks=true,
320          linkcolor={blue},
321          citecolor={green},
322          urlcolor={red},
323          pagecolor={cyan},
324          anchorcolor={black}
325       }
326       %\ifHy@nesting
327       \long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
328          \hyper@makecurrent{\@captype}%
329          \par\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}{%
330             \protect\numberline{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
331          \begingroup
332             \@parboxrestore
333             \if@minipage
334                \@setminipage
335             \fi
336             \normalsize
337             \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{%
338                \ignorespaces
339                \ifHy@nesting
340                   \hyper@@anchor{\@currentHref}{#3}%
341                \else
342                   \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@@anchor{\@currentHref}{\relax}}#3%
343                \fi
344             }%
345             \par
346          \endgroup
347       }
348       %\else
349       %\fi
350       \let\Hy@float@caption\@caption
351       \@ifpackageloaded{float}{%
352          \def\Hy@float@caption{%
353             \hyper@makecurrent{\@captype}%
354             \float@caption
355          }
356          \let\HyOrg@float@makebox\float@makebox
357          \renewcommand{\float@makebox}[1]{%
358             \HyOrg@float@makebox{%
359                #1\relax
360                \hyper@@anchor{\@currentHref}{\relax}%
361             }% \HyOrg@float@makebox
362          }% \renewcommand
363       }{}%
364    \else
```

This code is executed when `hyperref` is loaded; so `hypcap` can't do its patching (which should not be needed anyway) or, better, it already finds some conflicting code.

If the result is not what's expected, this must be considered a bug in the class.